# Program Batch Process in Data Loader

Tags: data-loader, schedulebatch, configuration, dataloader-batch

I'm looking for set an automated time-based batch with Data Loader..
So, i've followed these steps:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/command_line_intro.htm

i've copyed the edited process-conf.xml in: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin"

Started the process in cmd (admin privileges) with the command:
process.bat C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin testPROCESS

but i get this error: process-conf.xml not found in C:\Program\

so i moved that file in: 
"C:\Program\"

Started the process in cmd (admin privileges) with the command:
process.bat C:\Program testPROCESS

and get these errors:

---

```
2017-12-01 12:32:14,671 ERROR [testPROCESS] config.Config decryptProperty (Config.java:704) - 
Error loading parameter: sfdc.password of type: java.lang.Stringjavax.crypto.BadPaddingException: 
Given final block not properly padded
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:991)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineDoFinal(DESCipher.java:314)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.security.EncryptionUtil.decryptString(EncryptionUtil.java:210)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.config.Config.decryptProperty(Config.java:698)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.config.Config.postLoad(Config.java:655)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.config.Config.loadParameterOverrides(Config.java:678)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:120)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:100)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main(ProcessRunner.java:253)
2017-12-01 12:32:14,671 FATAL [main] process.ProcessRunner topLevelError (ProcessRunner.java:238) - 
Unable to run process AFFLEGinsertjava.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.salesforce.dataloader.exception.ParameterLoadException: 
Error loading parameter: sfdc.password of type: java.lang.String
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:162)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:100)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main(ProcessRunner.java:253)

Caused by: com.salesforce.dataloader.exception.ParameterLoadException: Error loading parameter: 
sfdc.password of type: java.lang.String
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.config.Config.decryptProperty(Config.java:705)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.config.Config.postLoad(Config.java:655)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.config.Config.loadParameterOverrides(Config.java:678)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:120)
        ... 2 more

Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:991)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineDoFinal(DESCipher.java:314)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.security.EncryptionUtil.decryptString(EncryptionUtil.java:210)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.config.Config.decryptProperty(Config.java:698)
        ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The data loader requires an [encrypted password](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_encryption.htm) for security reasons.

> When running Data Loader in batch mode from the command line, you must
> encrypt the following configuration parameters:
>
> - sfdc.password
> - sfdc.proxyPassword
>
> Data Loader offers an encryption utility to secure
> passwords specified in configuration files. This utility is used to
> encrypt passwords, but data that you transmit using Data Loader is not
> encrypted.
>
> Run \bin\encrypt.bat. At the command line, follow the
> prompts provided to execute the following actions:
>
> Generate a key
>
> Key text is generated on screen from the text you provide. Carefully copy
> the key text to a key file, omitting any leading or trailing spaces.
> The key file can then be used for encryption and decryption.
>
> Encrypt
> text
>
> Generates an encrypted version of a password or other text.
> Optionally, you can provide a key file for the encryption. In the
> configuration file, make sure that the encrypted text is copied
> precisely and the key file is mentioned.
>
> Verify encrypted text
>
> Given
> encrypted and decrypted versions of a password, verifies whether the
> encrypted password provided matches its decrypted version. A success
> or failure message is printed to the command line.

Also, your original command line failed because you forgot the quotes:

```
 process.bat "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin" testPROCESS
```

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox,

Yes i've generated the encrypted key according to the step 2 of the guide:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/command_line_intro.htm

Probably i've forgotten the quotes, thanks, i'll try asap.